# User creation feature is no longer visible

Tags: wordpress, account-creation, userprofile

We are using CiviCRM 5.68.1 on WordPress 6.4.2

Until recently, we were able to allow users to create their own WordPress userprofiles while filling out a Civi profile form.  These features are still enabled, but the username creation field is no longer visible at the top of the form.  Is this a bug with the new release of CiviCRM?  See screenshots below that confirm the features are enabled as they should be.

Thank you\

[image: Anyone can create a membership enabled on Wordpress]

[image: Account creation required on CiviProfile]

[image: Username creation field not displaying on page as it should be.]

Civi/Profile/Form.php  Starting at line 698

```
public function buildQuickForm(): void {
$this->add('hidden', 'gid', $this->_gid);
$this->assign('deleteRecord', $this->isDeleteMode());

switch ($this->_mode) {
  case self::MODE_CREATE:
  case self::MODE_EDIT:
  case self::MODE_REGISTER:
    CRM_Utils_Hook::buildProfile($this->_ufGroup['name']);
    break;

  case self::MODE_SEARCH:
    CRM_Utils_Hook::searchProfile($this->_ufGroup['name']);
    break;

  default:
}
```

Comment: Were you logged in by any chance when viewing the page?

Comment: I was logged in and logged off . It used to be visible either logged in or logged off.  It definitely should be visible when logged off.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Core regression bug, I have pushed a fix https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28970

Can you please apply the [patch][1] and test?

```
wget https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28970.patch

patch < 28970.patch
```

diff --git a/CRM/Profile/Form.php b/CRM/Profile/Form.php
index e20bd8d40b..f156b131d2 100644
--- a/CRM/Profile/Form.php
+++ b/CRM/Profile/Form.php
@@ -889,10 +889,10 @@ class CRM_Profile_Form extends CRM_Core_Form {
$this->setDefaultsValues();

```
 $action = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('action', 'String', $this, FALSE, NULL);
```

- $this->assign('showCMS', FALSE);
  if ($this->_mode == self::MODE_CREATE || $this->_mode == self::MODE_EDIT) {
  CRM_Core_BAO_CMSUser::buildForm($this, $this->_gid, $emailPresent, $action);
  }

- $this->assign('showCMS', FALSE);

  $this->assign('groupId', $this->_gid);

```
  [1]: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28970.patch
```

Comment: Thank you. I was about to try your patch, but we think your version is different that ours.  We are using CiviCRM 5.68.1  If your fix is the same version, please explain how to apply this patch.  I have updated my post with the lines in the Form.php file starting at line 698

Comment: I have updated my answer, the patch is for 5.68. Edit the file CRM/Profile/Form.php at line 892 add the + code and remove the - code from 896

Comment: The PR is now merged and will be part of 5.69 release

Comment: There was a release this morning which has a fix for this problem. Do you want to upgrade Civi and try?

Comment: The upgrade to 5.69.2 did NOT resolve the issue.  Are you getting different results when you install 5.69.21 on WordPress?

Comment: Now that I have upgraded to 5.69.2  and the issue is not resolved, I am afraid to try your patch, as you stated it is for 5.68.

Comment: The fix is available in 5.69.2 https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.69/release-notes/5.69.2.md, can you confirm if you have CRM/Profile/Form.php over-ridden?

Comment: Yes. CRM/Profile/Form.php was updated on 1/11/2024, the day I upgraded to 5.69.2.  Would you like to see it's contents?

Comment: Did you update CRM/Profile/Form.php again after upgrading Civi to 5.69.2? Because the changes were included in CRM/Profile/Form.php

Comment: I have not made any changed to CRM/Profile/Form.php

Comment: Did the problem got resolved?

Comment: No.  The problem has not been resolved.